# WSO2 ESB - HTML Response

Tags: html, rest, wso2, esb, wso2-esb

I built a GET REST webservice (Rest API) which has to return text/html.
Inside the sequence I have a Mediator where I invoke a webpage (like http://www.mypage.com or something), and get its contents into a String variable. 

After that I need to do some string replacements in the content and send it back as text/html to the client.

The problem is that when I got it back in my page the esb has replaced all `<html>` and other tags to `&lt;html&gt;` tags. So the web browser does not render a html page, but just writes the tags in the page itself.

The main idea is that it works like a proxy to a servlet, where I call a servlet, get the response, do some string replacements inside de html and javascript that I got, and send it to client.

Here is the sequence xml:

```
 <resource methods="GET" uri-template="/view">
  <inSequence>
     <log level="full"/>
     <header name="To" action="remove"/>
     <property name="URL" value="http://www.mypage.com"/>
     <sequence key="MyMediator"/>
     <property name="RESPONSE" value="true"/>
     <property name="NO_ENTITY_BODY" scope="axis2" action="remove"/>
     <property name="ContentType" value="text/html" scope="axis2"/>
     <enrich>
        <source type="property" clone="true" property="RESPONSE_MSG"/>
        <target type="body"/>
     </enrich>
     <send/>
  </inSequence>
```

So, I put the string variable with the html (got from the mediator MyMediator, which is a java class and invoke the webpage www.mypage.com) into a property 'RESPONSE_MSG' and then try to write it to the body (enrich).

In this case I get an error, because the property I set is a String and not a XML. 
If I use a payloadFactory instead of an enrich, then it will generate an XML and I will get the html tags with `&lt;html&gt;`.

I would like to know an effective way where I can send the string variable from the mediator and it does not get transformed into some xml where all the html tags into the string gets replaced by `&lt;` and `&gt;`. Or I can send it like in the above code without getting any error. Do I have to use another type for the variable that I put in the property RESPONSE_MSG?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem of the used messageFormatter (text/html). Check your axis2.xml file in the conf directory to see which messageFormatter is configured for the keyword text/html. Otherwise may try with a normal XML builder (i.e. application/xml).

Comment: I think the messageFormatter in the axis2.xml is ok, it's configured the **org.wso2.carbon.relay.ExpandingMessageFormatter** for "text/html" ContentType.  I put more information in the question to clarify it a little bit.